# Magento custom API for adding product wishlist

Tags: magento

I am implementing the magento custom API for wishlist.

Can anybody know, how to add the wishlist.

I tried using the  magento 'wishlist' module, but the product is not saving in to wishlist.

I am using the following function to save.

```
public function addNewItem($product, $customer_id, $buyRequest = null, $forciblySetQty = false)
    {
    }
```

I can able to get the wishlist using this post.
http://pastebin.com/G7ci0Mhu

Answer (score 0):

```
    This may help you

        <?php $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->load($_product->getId(),'product_id');
              if($wishlist->getId())
                  //product is added
              echo "Added! - Product is in the wishlist!";
              else
                  //add product to wishlist
              echo "<a href='".$this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ."'>Add This?</a>";
          ;?>

        Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->load($id)->delete();

        http://abhijitberadeveloper.blogspot.in/2012/07/product-add-wishlist.html
http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Wishlist/Mage_Wishlist_Helper_Data.html#methodgetWishlistItemCollection

http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Wishlist/Mage_Wishlist_Helper_Data.html#methodgetWishlistItemCollection
```